程　程度　度合　what’s the difference?
程　and 程度 as I’ve looked around don’t have the same usage but sometimes the same？ Both mean degree but that’s all I know about. And while watching some videos,I came across 度合 and it seems interchangeable with ほど(personal experience), so what’s the difference?
When to use it, how to use it, which are preferred and which are wrong?
